# Mixing .ts and .js in same directory

Tags: node.js, typescript

If you configure TypeScript to dump .js transpilations to the same directory as your .ts files, how can you tell node.js which files are the .js files you want to run since Node seems to not differentiate between file.js or file.ts or file.foo?

For example:

```
tsc.exe --out outputfile.js inputfile.ts
```

the files will be in the same directory, but how will node.js know which to read from to run?

(isn't it kinda dumb that node.js doesn't discriminate by file type?)

Comment: I've never had this problem. What exactly are you doing that's causing your issue?

Comment: You can [provide the full filename](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) -- `var mod = require('./file.js');`. Though, Node does check file extension, supporting 3 extensions itself -- `.js`, `.json`, and `.node`. Unless you're enabling support for `.ts` files, Node will not use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how will node.js know which to read from to run? (isn't it kinda dumb that node.js doesn't discriminate by file type?)

Not true. By default node will only look at `.node , .js, .json` files and will not try to load `.ts` files. E.g. `require('./foo')` will resolve to `foo.js` or `foo.json` or `foo.node`.